# Why do I get blurry pictures at far distances, but sharp results up close?

Tags: focus, image-quality, blur

I took this picture:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/91552641@N06/15828810701/

and if you look at the details (like the trees on the right side) they are all kinds of muddy. I had the same experience when trying to take some group family photos (I had the camera on a tripod then, so I don't think it was due to vibrations).

However, [this picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/91552641@N06/15830702505/) looks just fine.

And that seems to be pretty par for the course - I've tried different aperture values and zoom lengths, but it just seems like if I'm not focusing on something up close (less than 10' or so) then I just get a trashy image.

Is there anything I can do to fix/help this besides upgrading my equipment?

Comment: What _are_ you focusing on in the first picture?

Comment: I just had my focus set to "infinity"?

Comment: Manually? Did you do that by turning the focus ring as far as it will go?

Comment: Yeah, my focus ring [goes to infinity](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/images1/1870dx.jpg) o.O

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the comments, it seems like this is your problem — you're probably focusing *past* infinity. See [Why do some lenses focus past infinity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40995/why-do-some-lenses-focus-past-infinity)

Or, if you're not turning the ring all the way and instead relying on the marking, it may just be that the marking isn't precise enough.

Try the suggestions at [Where to focus when shooting landscapes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45106/where-to-focus-when-shooting-landscapes) instead.

Comment: I'm definitely cranking it all the way. I'll have to give that a try tomorrow and see what I get. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's _definitely_ it, then. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this experiment:

1. Stand in one place
2. Turn my iso as low as it will go (200)
3. Set my aperture as wide as possible (f/3.5)
4. Take a picture
5. Step my aperture one smaller, change shutter speed to compensate.
6. Repeat 5 and 6 until I hit the smalles aperture (f/22, in my case)
7. Turn my ISO <s>to 11</s> as high as it will go (1600 in my case)
8. Work my way back down the f-stops
9. Turn my ISO to something in the middle and work my way back up.

What I learned:

- With a wide open aperture *nothing* was in focus
- Until about f/14 things were still really blurry
- At f/22 I had the amount of sharpness in the scene that I was looking for.
- As expected, higher ISOs had more noise - but there was no real change in sharpness at the different f-stops

I also looked around on Flickr at photographs made with my camera model. There were *many* scenes that looked quite nice. Of course they were shot with entirely different lenses. I think that's probably a great way to get an idea of what a camera is capable of in the right hands (and post production tools).