# What is the right lens for photographing the northern lights?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, aurora-borealis

Im a complete amateur at photography. I recently bought a Nikon d3200 SLR with the 18-55mm lens kit. I've bought it specifically for my trip to Lapland to hopefully see the northern lights. Could someone please advise me on what lens would be best based on a low end budget?

Comment: This is already covered quite well in this question and answer, along with other tips and advise relating to the aurora borealis: [What tips and advice do you have for photographing the Aurora Borealis?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/what-tips-and-advice-do-you-have-for-photographing-the-aurora-borealis). Also note that "low end budget" can mean widely different things for different people. If all you have is your existing equipment, you will have to rely on technique and quite a bit of luck! If you can spend some money, look for wide angle Nikon primes with large apertures!

Comment: Make sure to browse the [tag:astrophotography] and [tag:aurora-borealis] tags!

Answer (score 1):

The lens is fine; you'll probably want to mostly use the wide end of the zoom range. What you really need is a tripod, since the exposure time will be on the order of seconds. With a "fast" lens (which the 18-55 unfortunately isn't), you could be able to grab handheld photos of especially bright auroras, but to get the sort of "amazing" shots you see on the Internet, you're going to need a tripod.