# Are there any resources or websites for finding areas which have low levels of light pollution at night?

Tags: night, long-exposure, light-pollution

Are there any websites which map light pollution levels so I know where to go for decent long exposure night shots? Or general resources for that matter?

Comment: It's easy. Just search for "low light pollution map" in a search engine of your choice and you will get a lot of good results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start at the [International Dark Sky Association](http://www.darksky.org/night-sky-conservation/36-ida/night-sky-conservation/91-darksky-finder-a-destinations). They have detailed maps for North America and also a link to the [Blue Marble Navigator](http://blue-marble.de/nightlights/2012) for the rest of the world. Although a little older, I find these [maps of North America](https://sites.google.com/site/3davel/home/light-pollution) more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your distance from light pollution is very important when capturing any night shots including auroras. I would recommend using the [Dark Sky Finder](http://www.jshine.net/astronomy/dark_sky/) (USA only) and trying to be at a minimum darkness of the blue areas of the map. This means that almost the entire eastern United States is not a great place to photograph auroras! You could still do it, but it just won't be optimal with all of the light pollution. The lights only occur from about 50-400 miles above the earth's surface, so light pollution isn't quite as impactful as star photography, but it still plays a role.

Another option to assess light pollution is the [Blue Marble Navigator](http://www.blue-marble.de/nightlights/2012), which works worldwide.

If you are interested in auroras in particular check out my previous answer here: [What tips and advice do you have for photographing the Aurora Borealis?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/what-tips-and-advice-do-you-have-for-photographing-the-aurora-borealis/43459#43459)