# shooting night sky photos with nikon d3300

Tags: astrophotography

I want to shoot night sky photos.

I have a Nikon D3300 DSLR with 50mm f/1.8D lens.
I have a tripod , and a timer cord.

Is my gear good enough to shoot night sky photos? 
Is there anything more I need?

Answer (score 1):

A 50mm lens on a APS-C DSLR is going to be quite a long effective focal length for general night sky photography. It isn't that you can't do it, the issue is more that you will start to see star trails very quickly with that length. If what you want is star trails then you should have all that you need to make an attempt.

Keep in mind that even more important than your equipment, is how dark the sky is where you are attempting to photograph. If you are anywhere near a city, you will struggle to get good results with any equipment. See this for more information: [Are there any resources or websites for finding areas which have low levels of light pollution at night?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47402/are-there-any-resources-or-websites-for-finding-areas-which-have-low-levels-of-l)

I would suggest browsing the astrophography tag here at this website and much more in depth information is available already for this exact same question - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article about long exposure and risks: [DSLR long exposures and sensor overheat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53076/dslr-long-exposures-and-sensor-overheat)

And you need good location (w/o ambient light) and some software for compass and stars/planets visibility.
If you provide more information in the question you will get more valuable answers

P.S. And one more point. I do not know where you will make the photos but on many places during the night it become quite cold. So do not forget to get warm clothes. And some torch to light around, set DSLR parameter for shoot and so on. And as @dpollitt mention this lens is a little bit too long. Something between 10mm and 25mm will help you to make better view on the sky